# Cron works, but scheduled job to open webpage in chrome does not

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, cron

Updates START

1. A friend of mine just answered this. I need to do this `export DISPLAY=:0 && <my GUI dependent command here>` Waiting for him to post the answer here.
2. I have tried `/opt/google/chrome/chrome PARTICULAR_GOOGLE_DOC_URL &` without the `&` too. Still fails. Succeeds directly on command line.
3. There is no `/var/log/cron` file on my machine. Subsidiary question: How can I get it?

Updates END

I have a Google Doc that I need to update at regular intervals multiple times a day. The content that would form a particular update cannot be predicted or determined programatically. So, the best solution I have is to have the particular Google Doc page open up automatically at fixed intervals and then I manually add the data to it.

Now, the problem is that what works directly on the command line does not work when used in crontab. Below is what I have tried (using 2mins interval just for testing) -

```
*/2 * * * * date >> /tmp/crontest
*/2 * * * * /opt/google/chrome/chrome PARTICULAR_GOOGLE_DOC_URL &
```

1. If I `cat /tmp/crontest` , I see timestamps added there for every 2nd minute
2. If I just try `/opt/google/chrome/chrome PARTICULAR_GOOGLE_DOC_URL` on the shell, it works as expected
3. But `PARTICULAR_GOOGLE_DOC_URL` does not get opened in my chrome every 2nd min as it should. (again: I am using 2mins interval just for testing)

What am I doing wrong? How should I fix this? Any alternate way of achieving what I need done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt this wil work, you test on the commandline probably included you running a normal graphical session where the browser could be opened? Because cron doesn't have such a session, so I suspect it will not be run.

Comment: It is probably a better solution to try and find an extension for chrome or firefox that automatically refreshes a given tab every N minutes.

Comment: @Nanne, you are right. A friend of mine just got me the right answer for this on IM. All I need to do is prepend my command with `export DISPLAY=:0 && ` in the cron. I have asked him to post the answer here so I can accept it and show gratitude by getting him karma-points :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit the crontab with `export DISPLAY` wrapper:

```
2 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && firefox %u
```

This opens an empty Firefox tab, you can use you favourite URL.

Comment: The best thing that worked for me was `0 */2 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /opt/google/chrome/chrome URL`

Comment: Didn't work for me: `export DISPLAY=:0 && firefox %u
Gtk-Message: 15:49:35.822: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
Error: cannot open display: :0`

Answer (score 7):

`cron` is intended for command line jobs, and runs commands with a [very limited set of environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with) - just `HOME`, `LOGNAME`, `PATH`, and `SHELL`.

At the least, `chrome` will require `DISPLAY` to be set. It may also be unhappy without other variables (eg, `DBUS` related ones). Run `env` in a terminal to see your current environment.

Comment: this answer provided the best learning. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The enviroment that you get for a cronjob is very limited. For example you dont get the DISPLAY varible wich is required to open chrome.

Wrap your command in a script

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0
/opt/google/chrome/chrome PARTICULAR_GOOGLE_DOC_URL
```

Not realy sure if you need more variables to get it to work. I made a similar script that started `konsole` (terminal in KDE) that worked in cron.

Comment: Not wrong at all, but a script was not needed, one liner in the crontab did it..

Comment: This worked best for me since my CRON task was kicking off a script!  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add setup your like this.

`2 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && ,<do what ever you want.>`

If this does not work, and you google-chrome or firefox not found, simply run the command below in your shell BASH, FISH, ZSH etc to get PATH.

`echo $PATH`

Whatever the result comes out from the above command just copy and paste it above your cronjob like this,

`PATH=<result from cmd>`

The reason of doing this, you might install the respective from snapd etc and that's why path is not defined as you downloaded from separate resource.

Comment: This is essentially a copy of the axisting anwers.

Comment: I was facing the same issue but could not found any answers, in the by cumulative resources i complied this up so others won't have face which I had.